# Short poem about a teleportation accident

Tags: story-identification, poem

This is on the tip of my tongue. It's a short poem, maybe only the length of a limerick about 2-3 people entering into a transport booth, and coming out mixed up. The final lines are something like "Bob left with Meg's heart. And Arnold got her legs."

Comment: That's from HHGttG.  "I teleported home one night with Ron and Sid and Meg.  Ron stole Meggie's heart away and I got Sidney's leg."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is from [*The Restaurant at the End of the Universe*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1312), Chapter 22, on the subject of matter transmission for transportation:

> And what about matter transference beams? Any form of transport which involved
> tearing you apart atom by atom, flinging those atoms through the sub-ether, and then
> jamming them back together again just when they were getting their first taste of
> freedom for years had to be bad news.
>
> Many people had thought exactly this before Arthur Dent and had even gone to the
> lengths of writing songs about it. Here is one that used regularly to be chanted by huge crowds outside the Sirius Cybernetics Corporation Teleport Systems factory on
> Happi-Werld III:
>
> Aldebaran's great, OK,
> Algol's pretty neat,
> Betelgeuse's pretty girls
> Will knock you off your feet.
> They'll do anything you like
> Real fast and then real slow,
> But if you have to take me apart to get me there
> Then I don't want to go.
>
> Singing,
> Take me apart, take me apart,
> What a way to roam
> And if you have to take me apart to get me there
> I'd rather stay at home.
>
> Sirius is paved with gold
> So I've heard it said
> By nuts who then go on to say
> "See Tau before you're dead."
> I'll gladly take the high road
> Or even take the low,
> But if you have to take me apart to get me there
> Then I, for one, won't go.
>
> Singing,
> Take me apart, take me apart,
> You must be off your head,
> And if you try to take me apart to get me there
> I'll stay right here in bed.
>
> ...and so on.  Another favorite song was much shorter:
>
> I teleported home one night
> With Ron and Sid and Meg.
> Ron stole Meggie's heart away
> And I got Sidney's leg.